# Obtener zscore para un df completo

Tags: scipy

Buen día a todos.

Estoy intentando obtener los valores z de una tabla completa de 4 columnas, pero me arroja NaN en 2 de ellas, el código que hice es el siguiente:

```
cols = list(norm.columns)
cols
out[]  ['desplazamiento', 'cilindros', 'consumo', 'co2']
for columna in cols:
col_zscore = columna + '_zscore'
norm[col_zscore] = stats.zscore(norm[columna])
norm.head()
```

[image: out[ ]]

Comment: No se de scipy, pero NaN no significa nulo, significa que no es un número, es decir, tienes la tabla preparada para mostrar un número, pero el valor pasado es otra cosa, probablemente un string. Te recomiendo que prepares la tabla para mostrar en texto y ver así de que se trata y luego, actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero los valores de las cuatro columnas son float e int (consumo), si la preparo para mostrar texto, ¿ya no podría hacer calculos con ella?

Comment: Solo temporalmente, para ver realmente qué valores se están mostrando

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo resolví.
Las columnas desplazamiento y cilindros tenían valores NaN en algunos registros, por lo que los rellene con la media fillna(mean()), despues de hacer eso ya funcionó el stats.zscore() para las 4 columnas.
Muchas gracias y buen día.

=)